# Can not add dynamically items to Owl Carousel in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I'm trying to dynamically add items to an Owl carousel. Here is how I'm doing it:

**HTML**

```
<div id="avatar-carousel" class="owl-carousel lesson-carousel">
                                            <div class="item item-logo">
                                              <div class="product-item">
                                                <div class="carousel-thumb" style="height: 77px!important;width: 70px;" >
                                                      <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100" alt="">
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                              <!-- Start Item -->
                                        </div>

                                        <button id="click">
                                        click
                                        </button>
```

**JS**

```
$("#avatar-carousel").owlCarousel({

      items: 5
  });

  $("#click").click(function(){
    $('#avatar-carousel').trigger('add.owl.carousel', ['<div class="item"><p>' + 'hh' + '</p></div>'])
                    .trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
  });
```

Nothing happens with this code. I can't see the error. Here is the fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hj2xh2Lz/1/).

**EDIT:**

Seems like the code is correct, as it's working in the fiddle. 
I forgot to mention that the carousel works just fine, it is loaded correctly in the beginning. The issue is when trying to add items. Nothing happens, no errors but items are not added.

Comment: you didn't saved the fiddle - its empty

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function`

Comment: You need to provide more info. Fix the fiddle (e.g., load the CSS/JS resources at the very least). I have a basic version working here: https://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/c1wkkt4L/3/

Comment: @DaveNewton , I really don't understand why this error occurs. The only difference between my code and Dave Newton's is the use of an intermediate var on his.

Comment: @DaveNewton. My bad, I did know that we can add external resources to the fiddle. The carousel.js file was missing. I just added it. So know it's working here. Though it's not in my code.

Comment: That's not the only difference-I wrap my code in an onReady, loaded the resources in a specific order, etc. I don't recall what I used for the "add item" triggerable event, but check that as well. Obviously there's a difference since I'm adding items.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There can be two regular errors:

1. The button does not exist in time you create `onclick` event.

   - make sure the button exists in time you assign the event.
2. The carousel is inside the `<form>` and clicking the button submits the entire form (pay attention at browser page loading). Error shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hj2xh2Lz/2/).

   - solution would be to [prevent default action](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) for the event:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#avatar-carousel").owlCarousel({
        nav: true,
        items: 5
    });

});

$("#click").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //-- prevent form submit
    $('#avatar-carousel').trigger('add.owl.carousel', ['<div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/140x100" alt=""></div>'])
        .trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="avatar-carousel" class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="item item-logo">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="click">
        click
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: There's no form I can see. Or a submit button. Doubt that's the issue.

Comment: It's a little bit different in the code I'm working on. I just put a button for simplification, but it is actually in an autocomplete change event. All things are executed normally, even a console.log after the owl.add trigger. However, the item adding itself does not work.

Comment: Maybe the carousel was not created that time, or something similar. Try to open console and directly execute the code `$('#avatar-carousel').trigger('add.owl.carousel', ['<div>WORKING</div>']);`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all answers here work perfectly, but not in my case. Probably the events that are called are in conflict with others. So I did it another way:

**Clear the content of the carousel**

```
$('#avatar-carousel').html('');
```

**Append the new content into the carousel**

```
imgs.forEach(function(img) {
  $('#avatar-carousel').append(createImgCarousel(img));
});
```

Where imgs is an array of image urls, and createImgCarousel a function that creates a carousel item.

**Finally reinitialize the carousel**

```
$("#avatar-carousel").owlCarousel({
  navigation: true,
  pagination: true,
  slideSpeed: 1000,
  stopOnHover: true,
  autoPlay: true,
  items: 5,
  itemsDesktopSmall: [1024, 3],
  itemsTablet: [600, 1],
  itemsMobile: [479, 1]
});
```

It's maybe not so clean, but it works for now !