# Active Class in Owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I generate item in owl carousel from JavaScript code but the item div in the carousel does not have active class here is my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  $(".owl-carousel").trigger('add.owl.carousel', [
      '<div class= "item">' +
      '<div class="flyout-content">' +
      '<h5>' + data[i].firstName + '</h5>' +
      '<h3>' + data[i].lastName + '</h3>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
    ]
  }
```

Comment: If you add items dynamically, you need to rebuild/refresh owl carousel.

Comment: @Pedram can you give an example ho w to implement the refresh event

Comment: For example, in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43502758) it add items by click, but it use `refresh` with `.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel')` in your case `$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('refresh');
`

Comment: @Pedram Thank you its work  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Pedram said i did that and i add if statment to check first index and its work here is the code in case someone need it

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
if(i == 0){
  $(".owl-carousel").trigger('add.owl.carousel', [
      '<div class= "item">' +
      '<div class="flyout-content">' +
      '<h5>' + data[i].firstName + '</h5>' +
      '<h3>' + data[i].lastName + '</h3>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
    ]);
   var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
   owl.owlCarousel();

   owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
   }
  }
```